# Fitting geometries together

Tags: three.js

Say you have one 'body' geometry (from OBJ file) and several different 'lens' geometries, of different sizes, that can be 'mounted' on the body object.

- How is the mount information best represented (I am thinking the data models for body and lens would need offset data representing the respective mount points)?
- In THREE.js, for a chosen lens/body pair would a Group be used to 'put together' the two pieces?

New to THREE.js (sorry). . .

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a good approach.